# TestNG tests with overlapping groups not working with excludeGroups in maven

Tags: maven, testng

I am attempting to segregate tests into groups, for example, a "FULL" execution group and a lighter "SMOKE" group. I want to have a default profile in the master pom that only runs the SMOKE group and then have the CI server activate a separate the FULL group which executes all tests.

However, I'm having a problem in getting maven/ testng to execute the SMOKE set only. When I add the FULL group to excludedGroups, no tests execute.

My effective-pom for the maven-surefire-plugin is this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <groups>USER</groups>
          <excludedGroups>FULL</excludedGroups>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <groups>USER</groups>
      <excludedGroups>FULL</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And my test classes are annotated thus:

```
@Test(groups = { "FULL", "SMOKE" }, enabled=true)
public void testOne() { }

@Test(groups = { "FULL" }, enabled=true)
public void testTwo() { }
```

Each class selects one representative test for the SMOKE test group. I have tried to omit the excludedGroups tag, and only have the groups tag set to SMOKE, but then all tests execute.

Any assistance in aiding my understanding of the testng groups hierarchy would be appreciated.

Comment: See more details for groups selection and advanced groups on [enter link description here](http://www.vazzolla.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is expected behavior not to run any tests when you give FULL in excludedGroups because it excludes all the test cases which have it. If you want to run only SMOKE, you only give SMOKE in groups as below.

```
<plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>default-test</id>
                  <phase>test</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>test</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <groups>SMOKE</groups>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

The above config is working fine for me.

below config runs only testTwo().

```
<configuration>
              <groups>FULL</groups>
              <excludedGroups>SMOKE</excludedGroups>
          </configuration>
```

The only case (i can think of) in which a test case gets executed even though it's explicitly excluded will be when some other test case depends(testng 'depends') on this test and that dependent test case is included for execution.